# VNC only over SSH

Tags: ssh, vnc

How can I configure VNC server so that it can be accessed only via SSH tunnel?

With the default VNC server setting, there are at least two ways for someone else to login to my computer: by directly logging into my VNC server and my SSH server. Two doors to worry about.

Comment: If your using CentOs there is a pretty useful guide on [here](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server#head-f4875017c8bdcb37fce770575ae8decf0e9f185d).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bind your VNC server to localhost and do an SSH proxy to your server and tunnel VNC (client) over said proxy.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is explained here:
[Reversing an ssh connection](http://www.vdomck.org/2005/11/21/reversing-an-ssh-connection/)